# What is the procedure for reporting a problem with the site?

Tags: support

To be more specific: I am trying to edit one of my old answer in order to update it --- [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/379123/can-i-zoom-out-windows-or-scale-the-whole-desktop) --- and the site hangs everytime I press the "save edits" button (more specifically: it stops as if saving and after a while it times out).

I checked with other answer and it's definitely not a problem with my user --- I can edit other answers all right.

I know that the probable best thing to do is wait until tomorrow and try again, but --- in case it is still there --- what I am supposed to do? Flag the answer for moderator attention? Or post here (as I am doing now)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flagging something for moderator attention should only be done if the actual question or answer itself needs to be reviewed by a moderator (and then possibly removed), not if there is a potential bug on that page. If you think that you have found a bug, post a report on it here and give it the [bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bug) tag.

Comment: Additionally, if a post isn't specifically a bug report, the [meta-tag:bug] tag should not be used.